# Codeigniter Curl

Tags: codeigniter, curl, file-upload

I am new to CI. I am uploading file from  a url(drop box file chooser) but now its uploading to the root directory. I want to know how I can give path to file upload inside the CURL functions.

below is the code .

```
     $curl = curl_init($url);
     $file = fopen(basename($url), 'wb');
     $file_name =(basename($url));
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     fclose($file);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to set file upload path on curl functon direct.
Please use of drop box api library in codeigniter link below.

```
drop box api :- https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-Dropbox-API-Library
```

and follow step.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. After uploaded the file I moved it to the different location using separate php code.

Comment: So curl dont allow to  upload the files  the place that I want. So after upload it I moved to the  server folder that I want  using separate php code. We can use rename or other methods for that..